# JavaCv - Use classifier file in javacv

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I use some tutorial From Python and C++ to create my own code for Guess the feeling in images , already found some code and created some code but for use some file , I don't know what it is and what must to do for using it in java Like [emotion_classifier_model.xml](https://github.com/rionaldichandraseta/facifier/blob/master/src/models/emotion_classifier_model.xml)

anyone can help me to share a code for using this file in JavaCv I will be grateful.(Need code to put image on it and guess the feeling with this xml file.)
[link to github from tutorial  I use](https://github.com/rionaldichandraseta/facifier)

I use CascadeClassifier From the package org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier and I think miss some point.
if you know some tutorial in java that use opencv or javacv that tutorial the train and use the trained data I will be grateful too , for sharing it with me.

Comment: Unfortunately, the opencv_traincascade application has been deprecated, so it's no longer possible to train new cascade classifiers, see https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13231

Comment: What can I do , and what replace method can do the same for me? @SamuelAudet

Comment: I would try use the DNN module as suggested here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13231#issuecomment-440577461